# How to get NavigationKey.up value in qml and c++?

Tags: qt, qml

Im beginner in qml. I have set KeyNavigation.up (in item up) to an id of another item (down).
Why i could't retrieve KeyNavigation.up like this in qml ?!

```
var x = down.KeyNavigation.up
```

UPDATE:
This is an example. why i couldn't get a.KeyNavigation.up ?

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    TextField {
        id: up
        KeyNavigation.down: down
    }

    TextField {
        id: down
        KeyNavigation.up: up
    }

    function fun(){
        var x = up.KeyNavigation.down
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually works.

I don't see where you're calling `fun()`, but if you for example add the line `onActiveFocusItemChanged: fun()` after `visible: true` you will see the `x` variable is OK.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500; height: 500

    onActiveFocusItemChanged: fun()

    function fun(){
        var x = up.KeyNavigation.down
        print("x = up.KeyNavigation.down: " + x.text)

        var y = x.KeyNavigation.up
        print("y = x.KeyNavigation.up: " + y.text)
    }

    TextField {
        id: up
        y: 50
        KeyNavigation.down: down
    }

    TextField {
        id: down
        y: 100
        KeyNavigation.up: up
    }
}
```

Comment: in your example, if i defined KeyNavigation.down in qml for item x too, can i write something like this ?

`var x=up.KeyNavigation.down; `

`var y=x.KeyNavigation.down`

Comment: Yes, of course. I've updated the answer although it should be `var y = x.KeyNavigation.up` if I follow your example.

Comment: You were right. I couldn't remember why my code didn't work, because when i try it again, it work like a charm.

Comment: btw what should i do with this question? should i delete it?

Comment: Well, your code had a little error, because it wasn't calling to `fun()`. There are also some interesting opinions below, so it's up to you. Follow your heart! :) And happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In qml, items have properties. And you should declare properties. Without your whole code i cannot really give you a more detailed answer. Just have a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

In QML, [`id`s must begin with a lowercase letter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute). If you're using Qt Creator, you'd see this problem as soon as you typed it. When you run the program, you'd see this error:

```
IDs cannot start with an uppercase letter
```

So, either you typed your code in manually for this question (bad idea) and you mistyped the `id`s, or you didn't run it, which would be strange.

Using a lowercase `id` works:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: print(a.KeyNavigation.up)

    Item {
        id: A

        KeyNavigation.up: b
    }

    Item {
        id: b
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: QQuickItem(0x596dcc9180)
```

Comment: thank you for mentioning. A and B are not real ids. I just want to distinct between 2 items. I updated the code

Comment: Why not just post the actual code the first time and save everyone from wasting their time?